# Start a Powerpoint slideshow from a slide without showing the first slide for a brief moment

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I think the title is self - explanatory.

I want to use a VBA macro to start the slideshow from a specific slide, for example the 5th one.
If i use

```
ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.Run.View.GotoSlide 5
```

it flashes the first slide for a brief moment. I want to get rid of that.

I'm thinking that it might be possible to show the slideshow with a black screen only, change the slide and then show the slideshow correctly, but I don't know how to start it as a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`With ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings
        .RangeType = ppShowSlideRange
        .StartingSlide = 5
        .Run
End With`

edit: .RangeType = ppShowSlideRange was missing.

Comment: Well this flashes the slideshow briefly and then I can't launch it in any way. Only a restart fixes it.

Comment: Okay, but this restricts the range. I tried setting it back to `ppShowAll`, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I guess having `SlideShowSettings.RangeType` at `ppShowAll` and `.StartingSlide` at anything other than 1 is what causes the behavior you described in the first comment. Turn `.StartingSlide` back to 1.

Comment: This doesn't work, unfortunately. I guess that SlideShowSettings only work before you call Run. Well, i'm gonna search more, maybe i'll find a solution.

Comment: You can always do this:

`Set shp = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 0, 0, ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Width, ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Height)
shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 0

ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.Run.View.GotoSlide 5

shp.Delete`

Comment: Yeah, i thought about that. Will see, i might actually use this if i don't find anything better. If you post this as an answer, i'll accept it.